# How to get notified when a file is uploaded?

Tags: php, notifications

I'm building a php application. It's a platform where users can exchange files.

I started by letting the users upload a file to a specified directory on a local server using php, now I would like to know how to each one of them could get notified when a new file is uploaded to their directory.

Here's the simple form and php code that I used for this

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
        $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
        if(isset($name)){
            if(!empty($name)){      
                $location = 'soumissions/';      
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                    echo 'uploaded';
                }
            }       
        }else {
            echo 'please uploaded';
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use a cronjob that will send the notifications and store these notifications in database so that you will not send the same notification twice.

Comment: You can use `is_uploaded_file() ` function

Comment: so tell us, you're one of those guys who posts a question, gets an answer that works and then takes off without saying anything, or accepting an answer; Yeah, I know your type.

Comment: i just voted for an answer, i hope this will help you and make you happy @Fred-ii-

Comment: I posted a comment under your other question, no response so I deleted it. We're not your personal valets you know, or doormen, waiting. We've better things to do than wait around. Good thing another person knows how to `@` someone; I got a response **4 days** after I posted a comment under their question (on vacation?). I don't keep tabs open for more than 10 mins. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uploads all files into only one folder, but from your question I assume, that every user should have his own folder and every user is able to upload the file into somebody else's folder as well.
If I got it right, then your code should have these changes:
http:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="text" name="foldername" id="foldername"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['file'])){
        $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
        $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        if (isset ($_POST['foldername'])) 
          { $foldername = strip_tags($_POST['foldername']);}
        else
          { $foldername = $_SESSION['user_name']; } /* Make the uploader's folder as default, normally are sessions used to login, so I used it in my example */
        if(isset($name)){
            if(!empty($name)){      
                $location = 'soumissions/' . $foldername . '/';      
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                    echo 'uploaded';
                    send_message($foldername); /* Call function to message the folder owner where the file was uploaded */
                }
            }       
        }else {
            echo 'please uploaded';
        }
    }
?>
```

And last thing - function to send the message. The easiest way is to have folders named in same way as usernames (or other stored namings of users), especially ones that you also have in session used to login. Then $foldername = $username , which can help you a lot.

```
function send_message ($user)
{ if ( $_SESSION['user_name'] != $user) //to just send messages to other users
  {  /* do whatever you want here, you can send e-mail or anything else. As parameter of recipient, use the name of folder that it was uploaded to, assuming it is named same as some user's credentials, for example usernames*/}
}
```

Also for HTML, you probably should let users to choose from already existing folders only, not let them to upload into any folder they want. So some list of folders instead of text input. 
The best way for that is to take mysql result of all usernames, make the folders corresponding to it , and generate list of these into dropdown menu inside the original form.

Resume:

- Users will have their own folder
- Every user can upload to
  anyone's folder, when he uploads to anyone else's folder, it will
  send message